# JavaScript override chrome the functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, flash

I have JavaScript which will load flash ad when flash enabled in browser and load jpeg ad when flash disabled.But in google-chrome 45 beta version,they are explicitly placing a play button on flash ad's.Is there any way to override that and play the flash ad with out play button.Is there any way to access the chrome browser settings in the javascript.Please let us know is there any way.

Comment: I sincerely hope not.

Comment: Thanks,but is there any way to play the flash ad automatically.Normally we will hit playbutton to play the flash,can we do it using js.

Comment: If that's default behaviour in Chrome then you're stuck with it.  It's not possible to change people browser settings from Javascript, and if it were then I guarantee that browser would be the least used browser in the world.

Comment: In mozilla if flash player is under blocked versions then we will get vuulnerable message on flash ad and alerts us to upgrade the browser plugin.Can we override that or its same as chrome not allowing to override.

Comment: consider this: you're asking how to disable a security feature without user interaction, thus creating spam or worse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that from Javascript. If there were one, the whole purpose of the click-to-play functionality (security, user experience with regards to annoying flash ads) would be defeated.

Edit, to clarify: Imagine there was a way for legitimate scripts to disable the check. How is the browser supposed to differentiate between "legitimate" flash applications and malware?

Comment: In mozilla if flash player is under blocked versions then we will get vuulnerable message on flash ad and alerts us to upgrade the browser plugin.Can we override that or its same as chrome not allowing to override.

Comment: There is a good reason for vulnerable/old versions being blocked. From a security perspective, what makes your code different from malware? Why should it be allowed to change the settings, and how is the browser supposed to e.g. allow your code to change them and deny malware from doing the same?

Comment: Thanks a lot for understandable reasoning.